# Google Charts - How can I create a Y-axis label with vertical text?

Tags: google-visualization

Here is the [original chart](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxr=1,0,50&chxtc=0,15|1,10|2,10&chxt=x,y,r&chbh=10,0,40&chs=1000x300&cht=bvg&chg=0,10&chm=D,008000,5,-1,1,1|r,993879,0,0.115,0.119|r,BBCCED,0,0.126,0.13|r,FFCC00,0,0.36,0.364|r,FF1D00,0,0.7,0.704|r,000099,0,0.42,0.424&chtt=Weekly+ACT+Discussion+Report&chxs=0,676767,11.5,0,lt,676767|1,676767,11.5,0,lt,676767|2,676767,11.5,0,lt,676767&chd=t:0,1,3,7,2,1,6,4|0,2,2,6,2,0,11,6|0,17,27,12,17,17,14,20|1,1,16,39,9,16,28,26|0,9,5,6,16,20,15,4|1,30,53,70,46,54,74,60&chds=0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,99.9&chdl=Al+Julian|Dale+Bartholomew|Jim+Spurling|Mike+Dixon|Scott+Donahy|TOTAL&chxl=0:|Wk53|Wk01|Wk02|Wk03|Wk04|Wk05|Wk06|Wk07&chco=993879,BBCCED,FFCC00,FF1D00,000099,8DC66D).

When adding a Y-axis label, it [looks like this](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|Wk53|Wk01|Wk02|Wk03|Wk04|Wk05|Wk06|Wk07|1:|%23+of+discussions+per+individual&chxp=1,25&chxr=1,0,50&chxs=0,676767,11.5,0,lt,676767|1,676767,11.5,0,lt,676767|2,676767,11.5,0,lt,676767&chxtc=0,15|1,10|2,10&chxt=x,y,r&chbh=10,0,40&chs=1000x300&cht=bvg&chco=993879,BBCCED,FFCC00,FF1D00,000099,8DC66D&chds=0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,50,0,99.9&chd=t:0,1,3,7,2,1,6,4|0,2,2,6,2,0,11,6|0,17,27,12,17,17,14,20|1,1,16,39,9,16,28,26|0,9,5,6,16,20,15,4|1,30,53,70,46,54,74,60&chdl=Al+Julian|Dale+Bartholomew|Jim+Spurling|Mike+Dixon|Scott+Donahy|TOTAL&chg=0,10&chm=D,008000,5,-1,1,1|r,993879,0,0.115,0.119|r,BBCCED,0,0.126,0.13|r,FFCC00,0,0.36,0.364|r,FF1D00,0,0.7,0.704|r,000099,0,0.42,0.424&chtt=Weekly+ACT+Discussion+Report).

How can I make that Y-axis label read vertically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can play around with it here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#combo_chart

The following is a combo chart that has a look similar to I think what you want.

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
  var rowData = [['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua  Guinea',
                  'Rwanda', 'Average'],
                 ['2004/05', 165, 938, 522, 998, 450, 614.6],
                 ['2005/06', 135, 1120, 599, 1268, 288, 682],
                 ['2006/07', 157, 1167, 587, 807, 397, 623],
                 ['2007/08', 139, 1110, 615, 968, 215, 609.4],
                 ['2008/09', 136, 691, 629, 1026, 366, 569.6]];

  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {title: "# of discussions per individual"},
    hAxis: {title: "Month"},
    seriesType: "bars",
    series: {5: {type: "line"}}
  });
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I need the chart to be drawn as an image with a link to chart.api.google.com.  The resulting image is attached to an email.  In your example, the chart is not an image.